# How and what should i pass in order to get value for { cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud } to IAM role?

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-iam

What I have done so far is-
    I have signed in user with Cognito identity, in return i get a **'session token'** which contains **'aud'** inside it. But while I pass token through headers, it's not recognizing. Its send back error,

```
       message: 'User: arn:aws:sts::4954355577:assumed-role/multi-test-application-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole/multi-test-application-dev-list is not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Query on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:4954355577:table/tenantTable',
```

Or Is this a wrong way? So if its wrong, What and How should I pass the data in order to get aud inside the IAM role for **${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud}**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot pass the aud as a global variable or an env variable. Once we get the credentials from an identity pool, which is the secret token, access key id, and session token. We need to create dynamodb instance using these credentials. So whenever we use dynamodb, the aud will be set as identity pool id.